# Preventing Watchdog crash in .NET MAUI app

Tags: mvvm, maui

I thought I figured this out but my .NET MAUI app still crashes with Watchdog termination error whenever getting and handling data takes a bit of time. What's the right pattern to make sure I don't tie up the UI thread?

I'm using the MVVM approach -- using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` to help me with that.

First, I wire up the `OnAppearing()` method to call my `InitAsync()` in my view model using this pattern:

```
// MyPage.xaml.cs
...
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   await _vm.InitAsync();

   //  I also tried the following
   // await Task.Run(async () => await _vm.InitAsync());
}
```

I typically have an `ObservableCollection<T>` in my view model that a `CollectionView` is bound to. So, my typical view model looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; } = new();

internal async Task InitAsync()
{
   try
   {
       await Task.Run(async () => {

           var students = await _myService.GetStudentsAsync();
           var teachers = await _myService.GetTeachersAsync();

           if(students != null && students.Count > 0)
              foreach(var item in students)
                 Students.Add(item);

       });
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      // Do someting about exception but in this case, I don't even hit the catch 
   }
}
```

I don't always have multiple API calls but sometimes I need to make them. Main point is that I should never tie up the UI thread and crash the app so I'm trying understand what's wrong with this pattern here?

P.S. As mentioned above, I don't see any errors by hitting a `catch` block but in the crash report from Sentry, I see the following as the cause of the crash:

> WatchdogTermination: The OS watchdog terminated your app, possibly
> because it overused RAM.

I don't believe the issue here is RAM over-usage. I read in an article that the error message they give you is somewhat generic. So, I'm thinking the issue is tying up the UI thread.

Nevertheless, I'd appreciate it if someone could point out potential issues with the pattern I use here, starting with the `OnAppearing()` in code behind to invoke my `InitAsync()` method in the view model.

UPDATE:

Two updates

First, adding the service part of the code to paint a full picture:

```
private static string _baseUrl = "https://myapi.example.com";
private static HttpClient _client;
public MyService()
{
   if(_client == null)
      _client = new HttpClient
      {
         BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl)
      };
}

public async Task<List<Student>> GetStudentsAsync()
{
   // Make API call through generic GET/POST methods I created
   var url = "/students";
   await GetAsync<List<Student>>(url);
}

private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>GetAsync(string url)
{
    var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

    // Internal checks e.g. HTTP response codes, etc. omitted for brevity
    return result;
}
```

The second update is that I figured out what was causing the Watchdog termination. I had done a sloppy copy and paste job in my XAML file and I misspelled the method name in my view model. Interestingly, the compilation process didn't catch it.

The moral of the story here is this:

1. Anything that causes a delay in the UI thread could trigger a Watchdog termination and in this particular case, it was a pretty trivial cause, though it was hard to pinpoint.
2. Unfortunately, the error message Watchdog termination generates is pretty generic and doesn't tell you much about what's really causing it.
3. Here's the most interesting one. I develop on Windows and typically tether my iPhone to my laptop. For the most part, this works nicely and the UI/UX fidelity I get is pretty close to running the app in production on a real device. With that said, during my testing while running the app on HotReload mode, I kept getting a generic Watchdog termination error. I then decided to package it and test it through TestFlight and all of a sudden, I got a meaningful error message in the crash report that pointed to the misspelled method name in my XAML file. I guess the real lesson here is not to rely on a tetherd device and Hotreload testing too much.

Comment: I can suggest few improvements, ObservableCollection fires notifications for a change, every time you add student. This should be avoided. You can use CommunityToolkit.MAUI EventToCommand behavior, to move OnAppearing event, from the page code to the VM code directly. Also, marking the method as async, and awaiting is enough. However, this is mostly quality of life improvement. What I need to see is MyService code, and the API call.

Comment: Actually, both suggestions are great and I appreciate them -- especially using EventToCommand for handling `OnAppearing()`. Please see the update section in original post for more info on service part of the code. Last but not least, I figured out what was causing the crash -- see the update. Nevertheless, getting suggestions on how to improve my coding patterns is great and I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam hey Sam, just curious, did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @user1623521 Yes, it’s all related to tying up the UI thread. I now use `Task.Run()` for long running processes. You really have to master what to run on UI thread and avoid using it for long running processes.